# Debugging 500 Internal Server Error on PHP running on IIS7 cluster

Tags: php, iis, iis-7

Recently my ISP switched our website to an IIS7.0 high availibility cluster. The website is running on PHP5.2.1 and I can only upload files (so no registry tweaks). I had tested the website before and everything seemed to be working, but now the checkout page fails with:

> 500 - Internal server error.
> There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

As error messages go, this isn't very informative. I've tried:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', $file_php_can_write_to );
```

but both don't seem to do anything.

Anyone know how to get better debugging output?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Edit : Looks like we have a [similar question in serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/19561/how-can-i-display-and-log-php-errors-on-iis7). Check it out

Turning off IIS7 custom errors will allow error responses from your application to be sent to remote clients without being censored by the IIS7’s custom errors module.

You can do this from the IIS7 Admin tool by running “Start>Run>inetmgr.exe”, selecting your website/application/virtual directory in the left-hand tree view, clicking on the “Error Pages” icon, clicking “Edit Feature Settings” action, and then selecting “Detailed Errors”

[Source](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/07/26/Troubleshoot-IIS7-errors-like-a-pro.aspx)

Comment: This does change things but now I'm getting a plain text: "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Comment: +1 I'm just using classic asp, and ran into this... same answer works for me.

Comment: Make sure when using PHP that your code contains error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); or that the php ini is set to display errors. It is mentioned in the link in the answer but I forgot it so mention it here again.

Comment: Edge-case, but in the case of Wordpress, navigating the backend (i.e. logged in pages) would cause the blank 500 page, whereas hitting e.g. the frontpage (not logged in) with `error_reporting` and `display_errors` enabled showed the error and source (file + line-no.)

Comment: Adding to that edge case, we had all our Wordpress sites on a legacy server down until I switched to "Detailed Errors" from "Detailed errors for local requests and custom error pages for remote requests."

Answer (score 1):

It's very common when you change server you cannot load your apps. I have solved this problem running `php.exe` instead of loading your apps on the browser:

1) Run it using the Command line `> C:\php\php.exe` OR

2) Run `Windows Explorer`, look for it, and double click on `c:\php\php.exe`.

3) You are gonna see what DLL's are having conflicts and causing the 500 error.

4) Solve the conflicts finding the right DLL's for your windows version and you should be able to see your apps through the browser.

The best of the lucks.

Answer (score -4):

IIS does this, it's really annoying and I could not find a fix, which is what caused me to switch to an Apache server for my local machine. Unfortunately, if you don't have control over your server, the best you can do is either test it locally on an apache set up or ask your host to allow the error messages.

I did some googling, [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/19561/how-can-i-display-and-log-php-errors-on-iis7)this looks like what you need. Wish that was around when I was trying to get IIS running.

Comment: I would personally prefer Apache myself, but this isn't as helpful as an answer could be.

Comment: Suggesting an alternative web server isn't very helpful. What if the OP doesn't have that kind of control?