# PHP session_start() failed unless error_log file set?

Tags: php, session, error-log

Ran into a weird situation that I was hoping someone could explain more fully to me.

We have a rather simple PHP site that is using session_start() to record some data between pages.  We had this up and working fine on one server (OS X) and then switched to another server (Windows Server2008).  It started causing "500 internal server error" messages on this new server.

The PHPinfo results between the two servers were nearly identical.  Both of them had log_error = Yes, and "error_log" = No Value.

However, in trying to identify more exactly what was going on (as IIS merely reported the HTTP error message, and nothing about the PHP error), I set the "error_log" path to a file somewhere.  This seemed to make something happy, because PHP started to work as expected.  It was NOT throwing an error anymore from the session_start() call!  There were no errors in the log file at this point.

So it seems that merely being able to HAVE a log file available made it happy and it stopped causing errors.  Can someone help me understand what is going on in the background there?

Thanks.
C

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with the use of sessions at all?

Comment: Sounds similar to the issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696867/debugging-500-internal-server-error-on-php-running-on-iis7-cluster

Comment: @Mike:  because if we comment out that one single line, stuff works great; uncommenting that single line then returns us to the "500..." errors.

Comment: @Machavity:  those questions talk about getting PHP to display errors, which is a small part of my question; the real issue I am trying to understand is why does turning the error_log file on appear to STOP the errors from occurring at all.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with error log file causing "500 internal server error". There may be any other reason for causing 500 server error. If the error is with error_log file the PHP/Apache would be crashed and error message would never shown. 500 error means error in Processing File.

I have also got the same error message many times. The real problem is the encoding of the file. While transferring the file from one type of OS to Another type of OS caused errors. You are also transferring the files from OS X to Windows and both have different file writing patterns.

The best way which resolve in my case, I create a new file and past the old code in New file and then try to run it, it go through.

Comment: That is a common cause of issues, yes, but I don't think that applies in this case.  We had no troubles getting things to run, without modifying the files, if we just toggled the error log file on.