# IIS webpage failing to load | Fast CGI related

Tags: php, iis, cgi, fastcgi

So I am running Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.

I have tried many things to get PHP working, so I have installed PHP 5.5 via Web platform installer and also installed CGI prior to that via server manager.

When I try to load the page, I get this error message which I don't seem to be able to solve:

[image]

Anyone have any solutions?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check to ensure your PHP actually runs from the command line. E.g. cd to the directory where PHP has been installed and then run "**php -v**". PHP should show it's version details or display errors if you are missing some system files.
- Check the Windows Event Log and look for errors around the time you load your webpage in IIS. There should be more detailed error messages about missing DLLs or configuration problems.
- I suspect you may not have the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) required by PHP 5.5. Not sure if the Web Platform installer installs this for you. Go to Add/Remove programs and see if you have this installed. The errors from one of the above sources should also help tell you if this is your problem.

Comment: Hello Dean, I have done the first suggestion and ran "php-v" but I get the message "the program can start because MSVCR110.dll is missing from your computer, try reinstalling".

Comment: This file is part of the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 that I mention in my third point. Install it and then run a php -v again.

Comment: Thanks alot, i already had the c++ redistrutable but for x64 instead of x86. All fixed now.

Comment: Great - with PHP on Windows you are generally better off using the zip install and doing all the steps manually, both so you know what is going on "beneath the hood" but also to make sure you have all the required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

this thread could be helpful: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1186717. In addition, I recommend install PHP for IIS (or reinstall it if is already installed): http://php.iis.net.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

when setting up php on windows I tend to make a manual setup to make sure i am in control of everything.

make sure you are using a non thread safe version

detailed instructions [here](http://ftduarte.blogspot.se/2012/12/installing-wordpress-locally-on-windows.html)

additionally, this may help
[Debugging 500 Internal Server Error on PHP running on IIS7 cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696867/debugging-500-internal-server-error-on-php-running-on-iis7-cluster)