# Is it possible for PHP to override the IIS query timeout on a per-call basis?

Tags: php, iis, iis-8

I have a PHP script that runs a number of database queries. One query is known to take a long time to run. For the call to that query only, I'd like to have the web server allow the request to run for a considerably long time.

I am using the PHP function [`set_time_limit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). When this is run on Apache, the web server respects the PHP function and allows the database call to run for an extended time. With *IIS*, however, I was getting a `500 Internal Server error`. [Turning off *IIS* custom errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1696885/3714936) allowed me to get a more helpful error message, which was `The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout`.

Any number of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902554/fastcgi-process-exceeded-configured-activity-timeout) on this site talk about configuring either PHP or *IIS* to set a longer run time for requests - but these are all global settings for the web server / PHP.

> My question is: Can I facilitate allowing a longer request time **for a single request**, from PHP when the web server is *IIS* (ie. exactly as intended by `set_time_limit`)? Can you tell *IIS* to turn off its global time limit and respect the request coming from PHP?

Comment: Yes, you can set the timeout attribute in the FastCGI Settings component in iis.

Comment: Isn't that a server-wide setting affecting every website on every request?

Comment: Different websites have different FastCGI, so the setting is only for a single website.

Comment: Instructions in the linked Q&A say to select the server in order to set this setting. I looked first at website-level settings and could not find the FastCGI settings. While per-website would be better, it's still not best - which would be configurable per-request.